# disable adding of <p> tags in odoo list view with input fields Html

Tags: python, xml, treeview, odoo-9

in my py :

```
issue = fields.Html('name of field')
```

in my xml :

```
<tree>
<field name="issue"/>
</tree>
```

and the result in tree like this :

[image]

so, how to disable `<p><br></p>` tags from tree view.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml to

`<tree>
<field name="issue" widget="html"/>
</tree>`

Answer (score 0):

In odoo v9, to display a rendered HTML content in treeview you have to override the file in web module '/web/static/src/js/views/list_view.js' and declare a variable:

```
var ColumnHtml = Column.extend({
     _format: function (row_data, options) {
        return formats.format_value(row_data[this.id].value, this,options.value_if_empty);
     }
});
```

Add this variable to **list_widget_registry** variable like:

```
list_widget_registry.add('field', Column).........add('field.html', ColumnHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your custom module .js:

```
odoo.define('your_custom_module.ListView', function (require) {
"use strict";

var ListView = require('web.ListView');
var formats = require('web.formats');
var core = require('web.core');
var list_widget_registry = core.list_widget_registry;

var ColumnHtml = ListView.Column.extend({
     format: function (row_data, options) {
        return formats.format_value(row_data[this.id].value, this,options.value_if_empty);
     },
});

list_widget_registry.add('field.html', ColumnHtml);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue in 15.0. `t-raw` is now obsolete in QWeb and `t-out` is the only thing available, so whatever we want to output has to be either plain text, or wrapped into `markupsafe.Markup()` which is exactly what `fields.Html()` does. However, as OP demonstrated, a field declared this way adds extra `<p>` tags.

To disable this, add `sanitize=False`, like so:

```
issue = fields.Html('name of field', sanitize=False)
```